# How JavaScript decides what size of memory to allocate for a numeric value?

Tags: javascript, memory, memory-management

Programming languages like Java / C has int, long , byte etc that suggest interpreter exactly how much memory it should allocate for a number at run-time . This saves a lot of memory if you are dealing with large number of variables.

I'm wondering how programming languages , who doesn't have this primitive variable type declaration (JavaScript , Ruby) , decides how much memory to allocate for lets say `var a = 1` . If it allocates lets say 1 byte ,then in the next line if I do `a = 99999999999` , it will have to swipe out that variable and reallocate. Won't it be an expensive operation ?

Or does they allocate a very big memory space for all the variables so that `one size fit all`

Comment: If you double the allocation everytime you hit a limit, your amortized complexity of operation will still be O(1).

Comment: Yah but how the initial value is decided ?  If `var a = fxThatReturnNo()` , how inter preter decides the initial size of a ? It will wait for the function call to resolve ?

Comment: _internally, JavaScript represents all numbers as floating-point values_ [Number Data Type in javascript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/data-types-javascript#number-data-type)

Comment: The memory can be reserved when actually the assignment is done.

Comment: *"for a numeric variable?"* - Note that JavaScript doesn't have numeric *variables*, only numeric *values*. The next line after `var a = 1` could be `a = 'a string'`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY That's what I guessed . They are allocating a very big floating-point size for all numeric values . That's `one size fit all` . Isn't that extremely inefficient memory management ?

Comment: I think it is not as efficient as you think. Other languages use fixed size int depending on the size of an integer and extend it to a multiple precision integer. It depends on the way of thinking in language implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is a good explanation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Internals)

> JavaScript values
>
> The type JS::Value represents a JavaScript value.
>
> The representation is 64 bits and uses NaN-boxing on all platforms,
>   although the exact NaN-boxing format depends on the platform.
>   NaN-boxing is a technique based on the fact that in IEEE-754 there are
>   2**53-2 different bit patterns that all represent NaN. Hence, we can
>   encode any floating-point value as a C++ double (noting that
>   JavaScript NaN must be represented as one canonical NaN format). Other
>   values are encoded as a value and a type tag:
>
> On x86, ARM, and similar 32-bit platforms, we use what we call
>   "nunboxing", in which non-double values are a 32-bit type tag and a
>   32-bit payload, which is normally either a pointer or a signed 32-bit
>   integer. There are a few special values: NullValue(),
>   UndefinedValue(), TrueValue() and FalseValue(). On x64 and similar
>   64-bit platforms, pointers are longer than 32 bits, so we can't use
>   the nunboxing format. Instead, we use "punboxing", which has 17 bits
>   of tag and 47 bits of payload. Only JIT code really depends on the
>   layout--everything else in the engine interacts with values through
>   functions like val.isDouble(). Most parts of the JIT also avoid
>   depending directly on the layout: the files PunboxAssembler.h and
>   NunboxAssembler.h are used to generate native code that depends on the
>   value layout.
>
> Objects consist of a possibly shared structural description, called
>   the map or scope; and unshared property values in a vector, called the
>   slots. Each property has an id, either a nonnegative integer or an
>   atom (unique string), with the same tagged-pointer encoding as a
>   jsval.
>
> The atom manager consists of a hash table associating strings uniquely
>   with scanner/parser information such as keyword type, index in script
>   or function literal pool, etc. Atoms play three roles: as literals
>   referred to by unaligned 16-bit immediate bytecode operands, as unique
>   string descriptors for efficient property name hashing, and as members
>   of the root GC set for exact GC.

*According to W3Schools:*

> This format stores numbers in 64 bits, where the number (the fraction)
>   is stored in bits 0 to 51, the exponent in bits 52 to 62, and the sign
>   in bit 63:

Value (aka Fraction/Mantissa): 52 bits (0 - 51)
Exponent: 11 bits (52 - 62)
Sign: 1 bit (63)

Also read this article [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management).

Comment: I'm sorry it wasn't completely clear . It suggests they assign double for all the variables , Isn't that extremely inefficient memory management ?

Comment: @sapy Yes, it is. But that's how it does it. JavaScript does not have a `float` and `int` type, so the memory management is generic for all number formats.

Comment: @sapy that's a quite broad generalization. The efficiency of an implementation is only meaningful with the context of a use case.

Comment: @sapy It is a trade-off among space, speed, and complexity. As you noted in the question, having variable-sized variables creates significant complexity (and also increases size, since somebody needs to keep track of how big the variable is now and where to find it in memory, which means you already are paying for a pointer.)